Sequelize associations: Is it possible to load properties of association directly to the basic Model?
When I do a select in sequelize with associations I Always get them as nested objects.
Is it possible to get them instead as properties of the basic Model?

Only using extended syntax of attributes indicating them one by one and giving them aliases like like [[Sequelize.col('AssocitedModel.col'), 'alias'], ... other attributes]
